# Badly designed application: should we rewrite?

Tags: javascript, architecture, project

When you work on an application that has a bad architecture and you definitely know it won't support well a scale up, what would be the best solution to improve the app?

The app I work on has been built in a very bad way, is difficult to understand and took about 6 months to develop. Although I just arrived on this project and we need to take decisions.

- Would you rewrite everything?
- Would you refactor piece per piece?
- Would you keep it as it and add new features with a better design?

Considering time is money how would you argue about the right solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends from person to person. For me, I would leave the rest as it is. But I would start developing the new activities or features in the right designed way. 
And once you finish everything, then make it a little better by refactoring the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would try to rewrite the parts that just don't seem to work or are the most difficult to understand.
2. Try to let your team explain the code, they made it, so they know how it works :)
   If there are any problems ask them they might sure know how to solve them.

*Errors are also made by humans, but we try to learn from it..*

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that this can be answered in a general way. But I could ask some questions and the answeres could leed you to a descision:

1. What has caused the bad design?
2. Are you able to change the conditions that led to the problems? If not, you might face the same problems in your second attempt while rebuilding from scratch and your second version might also have design flaws.
3. Do you understand the code good enough to refactor it?
4. Do you have exclusive time for Refactoring? If you need to do that by the way, you won't be able to refactor bigger things
5. How good are your tests? Will they uncover new mistakes that will likely appear while refactoring?
6. Are you able to rebuild the app  without support by your customer? If not, will you get that support?
7. Are you able to estimate the costs of a redesign and the refactoring? Are you able to pay that?

Comment: 1. Bad design has been caused by non-experimented developers. I've been brought to the project to help. 2. I am more experienced than the team and have better idea how it could be designed, although the current state makes me wondering what would be the best solution to do. 3. I don't understand the entire code enough yet and are working on learning it more at the moment. 4. Yes we have exclusive time for refactoring or rewrite assigned. 5. Many tests are bad tests we need to rewrite. 6. We can get support from the customer (internal). 7. Not sure yet what would be the fastest solution...

Comment: 1. Are you able to teach the unexperienced developers, or will you rebuild the app alone?

Comment: 1. Definitely there would be a mentoring and teaching around the rebuilding - But mostly my question was what makes you take one decision or another? I know you can never be sure, but which factors would be keys?